# Money Conversion using IF THEN in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my table
[image]
I want to Select the price only in DOLLAR (I mean if the price is in AFG Unit multiply that by 68)
I tried this `SELECT Price, IF (Unit='AFG' , Price*2)  FROM sales` But didnt work

Comment: Why would you add 2 when you want to multiply by 68?

Comment: Remove the space between IF and (. Also you need to add another parameter to the function for when it is false. `IF(Unit='AFG', Price*68,Price) as Price`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Unit, 
    case Unit when 'AFG' then Price * 68 
              else Price end as 'Price'
FROM sales
```

Answer (score 1):

`IF()` is a function in MySQL. There's no space between the function name `IF` and the parameters `(condition, if true, if false)`

Additionally your function is missing the 3rd parameter, which is what the function returns when the condition is false.

Corrected query:

```
SELECT IF(Unit='AFG', Price*68, Price) As Price 
FROM Sales
```